# How to set Background colour for the Table column inside the TableRow

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I am having TableRow. Inside the table Row I am having some textview.

Textview height should be wrap_content for my requirement.

If I give Background colour It will be set to the Textview. It won't fill the entire row.

Just like the below Image

[image]

But What I need is background should be set to entire column instead of textview.

Here I have added my code.

```
<TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subject"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="198"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Subject"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="98"
            android:background="@color/colorSecondary"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Date"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Time"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="98"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Time"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>

    </TableRow>
```

Comment: set the background color in ID tableRow instead of subject. Also replace ></TextView> with /> . It makes for tidier code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change layout_height to match_parent in all TextView.

Comment: @MathaN if i helped you, please accept my answer :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

if Textview android:layout_height="wrap_content" is your requirement do this In tablerow take linear or relative place background color .inside this layout place textview.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want the height to be wrap parent in that case you need to create three linear layouts and define its background to the background color of your textView. But its quite an overhead if you could share why you need it than maybe can suggest a better solution.